# Difference between SiftFeatureDetector() and Ptr<FeatureDetector>

Tags: opencv, sift, feature-detection, surf

Whats the difference between SiftFeatureDetector() and Ptr. They both apparently have the same function. The [opencv tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection) uses SiftFeatureDetector but when [clicking on the official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=surffeaturedetector#featuredetector) they use Ptr and have no mention of SiftFeatureDetector(), so I cant read up on it. as in the tutorial they used this: `int minHessian = 400;  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );` and I dont know what the minHessian is supposed to do.

Also I tried them both on the same image and they both have the same result, then why are they different?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//initModule_nonfree();
Mat img;

img = imread("c:\\box.png", 0);

//cvtColor( img, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY );

 //SiftFeatureDetector detector;
//vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
//detector.detect(img, keypoints);

Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature_detector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

feature_detector->detect(img, keypoints);

Mat output;

drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, output, Scalar::all(-1));

namedWindow("meh", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("meh", output);
waitKey(0);



return 0;
```

}

Thank you

Comment: FeatureDector is an interface (abstract class), SiftFeatureDetector is a concrete subclass of FeatureDetector. Ptr<T> is a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to an instance of class T, to ensure it is properly deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: See the correction by @gantzer89 in the comments below.**  (Leaving my original text in place for historical clarity.)

---

In my general experience, using the FeatureDetector::create() syntax (discussed [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=surffeaturedetector#featuredetector-create) in the "official documentation" you cited) allows the flexibility to specify your algorithm at runtime via a parameter file, while the more specific classes, such as SiftFeatureDetector, provide more opportunities for customization.

The create() methods start with a set of default algorith-specific parameters, while the algorithim-specific classes allow customization of these parameters upon construction.  Thus, the create() method is assigning a default value to minHessian, while the SiftFeatureDetector constructor provides the opportunity to choose a value of minHessian.

As a rule of thumb, if you want to quickly experiment with *which* algorithm to use, use the create() syntax, and if you want to experiment with fine-tuning a particular algorithm, use the algorithm-specific class constructor.

Comment: This is not true, using FeatureDetector::create for detector instantiation allows as well tuning parameters since detector is also a cv::Algorithm and hence its parameters might be changed using cv::Algorithm::set. And if the available parameters are not known they can be easily retrieved looking at the output of cv::Algorithm::getParams

Comment: can I set the minHessian somehow (for the `create()`) ?